# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userLocation.coords.latitude')

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I'm a little confused with Promises in JavaScript, as the documentation said these functions for getting permission and user location returns a promise and I used `then()` do to things on queue. which I understand what is a promise so far but I don't know why this is not working and telling me this. the whole things is I need to get user coordinate first and then get user address via coordinates. here is my code:

```js
const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    Location.requestPermissionsAsync().then((permission)=> {
      if(permission.granted) {
        Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({accuracy: 5}).then((result) => {
          setUserLocation(result)
        })
        .then(() => {
          Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({latitude: userLocation.coords.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coords.longitude}).then((arr) => {
            console.log(arr)
          })
        })
      }

    })
  }, [])
```

Comment: State setting is also asynchronous in React. Your last `then()` runs before userLocation is set

Comment: ty sir @charlietfl